# The attribute 'name' already exists DTSX XSD

Tags: xml, vb.net, ssis, xsd

I have dozens of SSIS Packages, extracting numerous columns from various sources. Whenever there is a change in the source data, I need to be able to see which SSIS Package is affected, and it starts to be hard to maintain manually.

Therefore, I would like to read the SSIS Packages stored as `.dtsx` files to retrieve the relevant information:

- input and output columns names and types
- source and destination table names
- type of connection used

With Microsoft providing the XSD for this DTSX format online: [Appendix A: Full DTSX XSD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_data_portability/ms-dtsx/61d22b48-f3d3-4ef9-b5c3-c70598a4d688?redirectedfrom=MSDN), I thought I would be able to create a vb.net class using `xsd 'myfile'.xsd /classes /language:vb`.

However, having a first look at the `.xsd` in Visual Studio, I am facing the same warning multiple times:

> The attribute 'name' already exists.

I have made sure all the `.xsd` referenced have proper naming and are in the correct folder.

[image]

When trying to use the `xsd` command in the Visual Studio command prompt, the class actually gets written, but I get a warning:

> Schema validation warning: The attribute 'name' already exists. Line 971, position 8.
> Schema validation warning: The attribute 'name' already exists. Line 990, position 8.
> Schema validation warning: The attribute 'name' already exists. Line 997, position 8.
> Schema validation warning: The attribute 'name' already exists. Line 1607, position 14.
> Schema validation warning: The attribute 'name' already exists. Line 1620, position 14.
> Schema validation warning: The attribute 'name' already exists. Line 1673, position 14.
> Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with the above? Is there any workaround to tackle those warnings?

Answer (score 1):

If the code compiles correctly and it works for your purposes, then I think it would be OK to ignore for now. The warnings are being produced due to errors in the schema file itself, so it's not you.

If you run the full DTSX schema through an XSD validator (like Xerces), you get the exact errors that seem to correspond to the warnings being generated by XSD.exe in your own output:

- Error for type '*PipelineComponentPropertyType*'. Duplicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace are specified.  Name of duplicate attribute use is '*name*'.
- Error for type '*PipelineComponentOutputPropertyType*'. Duplicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace are specified.  Name of duplicate attribute use is '*name*'.
- Error for type '*PipelineComponentInputPropertyType*'. Duplicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace are specified.  Name of duplicate attribute use is '*name*'.
- Error for type '*PipelineComponentInputColumnPropertyType*'. Duplicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace are specified.  Name of duplicate attribute use is '*name*'.
- Error for type '*PipelineComponentOutputColumnPropertyType*'. Duplicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace are specified.  Name of duplicate attribute use is '*name*'.

So the issue is basically this: the **Pipeline** types mentioned above use an attribute group that contains a 'name' attribute, but those same types also locally define another attribute also called 'name' that uses a different type. Here's a diagram of the issue with the duplicate 'name' attributes highlighted:
[image: duplicate name attribute in DTSX schema]

You could try to fix the schema yourself if you wanted to, by creating another copy of the **"DTS:PipelineComponentPropertyAttributeGroup"** attribute group and remove the 'name' attribute and use that one on all the PipeLine types that report the warning, but it's a bit difficult to tell what Microsoft meant.

Maybe they meant to override the **"DTS:PipelineComponentPropertyAttributeGroup"** name attribute with the locally defined one? Or maybe the presence of the **"DTS:PipelineComponentPropertyAttributeGroup"** attribute group is incorrect and it just shouldn't be there. Hard to tell unless one is intimately familiar with how the DTSX tool works or have an existing DTSX file that might indicate how the 'name' attribute is meant to be properly used.